# How to merge two content source in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In my share point 2010 website, I added two content source

1. file system (shared folder)
2. BDC data (Line of Business Data)

[image: External Content Source]

I added the managed properties to map the metadata of the BDC data.

My search result coming link this

[image: Search result]

I would like to link the two content source, my second content source having the file related information like (tab, category, fileno, case name)

I added the column and also I altered the xslt in the search result web part. the results are coming link below.

[image: Modified Search result]

From the result, the third one (120) is coming from the database so all the properties are mapped (caseid, casename,fileno, doctab, description)

But it's not mapping to the file system. The file system having relationship with the table with the file name and also the the path of the files having some information:

file://192.168.25.231/FolderName/**CaseID**/**documenttab**/**filename**

CaseId is the primary key for the table which I added as second content source.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This may be an overly simplistic explanation to keep the response as short as possible.

For your search results page, the best approach when also retrieving application data is to not present that information in the core search results web part. Exclude it from the default scope. Instead, use a federated search results web part added to the results page. You'll also need to create the corresponding federation location for the scope (easy to do), and you can then use XSLT to style the display of the results - application data needs to be presented differently to links to files and web pages.

Then, a search for say the case ID, will display all files containing that information in the core search results web part, and will display any matching application data in the federated results web part, with the different formatting applied. Note - there will be no connection between the two. The only relationship is that they both match the search query. It is possible to connect web parts to filter one based on the selected value in another, but it's an entirely different approach and not easily done using search results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with the federated search result getting same result.
The Location i specified is "Local Search result" and added the column in fetched properties and altered the xsl under display properties of the federated search result web part. still i am getting the same result, without mapping to the customized properties caseid, casename. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it's difficult to add much more without seeing the environment. But here's plan B

Given you're using the BCS and want to display both unstructured content (the files) and application data that shares metadata with the files, you could try the following. It will require some coding knowledge. You can make connections between web parts in SharePoint Designer but this will need Visual Studio

- create a custom search results web page, and use the standard core search results web part along with separate data web part for displaying the application data
- create a custom query box for entering the search query, probably best done with separate fields for the metadata - case ID, case name etc. (You'd normally use a data filter web part, but that won't pass results through to the normal search results - you need to code to run two queries)
- format and pass the query to both the core search results web part, and the BCS data web part, to display items that match the query

That's probably as much as I can help with. The SharePoint section on MSDN should be the next port of call. Good luck!